# What is lsh_ used for and/or what is it doing?

Tags: shell, programming

I am new to programming in Linux and I am quite confused. I notice the `lsh_` prefix is used for function names [here](https://brennan.io/2015/01/16/write-a-shell-in-c/). I'm not sure why.

The only thing I can find on the internet is that `lsh` could possibly mean "limited shell". However, it is not clear. If that is what it means, what is a "limited shell" and how or why are we using it?

example: `lsh_loop()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article points to https://github.com/brenns10/lsh and in
https://github.com/brenns10/lsh/blob/master/src/main.c#L9 it says:

```
@brief        LSH (Libstephen SHell)
```

So `lsh` stands for `Libstephen SHell`.

`libstephen` is also a name of another repository of the same user
https://github.com/brenns10/libstephen.

Answer (score 0):

It is an implementation of the SSH protocol. Just like OpenSSH.

However `lsh` is not really fit for use. I copy below from the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsh):

> Karim Yaghmour concluded in 2003 that lsh was "not fit for use" in production embedded Linux systems, because of its dependencies upon other software packages that have a multiplicity of further dependencies. The lsh package requires the GNU MP library, zlib, and liboop, the latter of which in turn requires GLib, which then requires pkg-config. Yaghmour further notes that lsh suffers from cross-compilation problems that it inherits from glib. "If […] your target isn't the same architecture as your host," he states, "LSH isn't a practical choice at this time."[10]